# Break consecutive for loops after n iterations

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have the following code, it works so far, but after it reaches the 6th iteration it jumps from loop `for i in range(1,6):` to the loop `for filename in files:` and enter the loop `for i in range(1,6):` again. So it's doing a calculation again. This repeats in general 3 times and after that it's done. I tried already with `if else` but somehow it doesn't work here. So I need that the script stops after it did the calculation and reached once the `i=6` and not 3 times the same calculation.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/Users/path....'):
    
       for filename in files:
    
            for i in range(1,6):
                
               #Calculation
            
               print(results)
```

Comment: Are there three files or three levels of folders ? That would be expected behaviour then.

Comment: The folder structure is as follows:
Main folder with two Sub folders.
And in each Sub folder are 5 data files.

Answer (score 2):

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/Users/path....'):
    for i, filename in enumerate(files, 1):
        # Calculation
        print(results)
        if i == 6:
            break
```

But I’m not really sure what you try to accomplish.

Could you be more specific by giving example of you actual output and the directory structures?

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe it, your code seems to be doing what it's supposed to. If `files` contains 5 elements, then your calculation function will be run 30 times for each cycle of the outermost loop (assuming every single cycle yields 5 `file`s). What is it that you're trying to accomplish with this loop structure? Maybe if you explain your desired outcome we can help.